# Actionscript 3 Menu with dynamically loaded options and mouse overs

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

working on (as the title states) a menu with dynamically loaded options with mouse overs.

The chain of events as I see it (this could be flawed) is:

•Use loop to place one empty MovieClip for each entry in the XML file, down a number of pixels each time. We will call these 'entries'.

•Inside each entry add a textField (text from XML), draw a rectangle with alpha=0 (to be the highlight on mouseover), and add another movieclip from the library.

•Add mouseover & mouseout eventListeners to each 'entry' which set the invisible rectangle to alpha=1, and change the color of the text and movieclip from library.

Following is the function that initiates all of this. *edit: Fixed more really dumb stuff.

```
//Load List Options
function loadHighlight():void
{
    var yTmp:Number = 0; 
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < photo_total; i++)
    {
        var Highlight:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        photoHighlights[i] = Highlight;
        photoHighlights[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, highlightOvr);

        //Draw Invisible Rectangle
        var rectngle:Shape = new Shape();
        rectngles[i] = rectngle;
        rectngles[i].graphics.beginFill (0x0DAC54);
        rectngles[i].graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 1170, 144);
        rectngles[i].graphics.endFill();
        rectngles[i].alpha = 0;
        rectngles[i].y=yTmp;
        rectngles[i].x= 0;
        photoHighlights[i].addChildAt(rectngles[i], 0);


        //Load photosArray
        var photoname = photo_data[i].@TEXT;;
        var photolist:TextField = new TextField();
        photosArray[i] = photolist;
        photosArray[i].textColor = 0x0DAC54;
        photosArray[i].x = 26.95;
        photosArray[i].y = 92.65;
        photosArray[i].embedFonts = true;
        photosArray[i].antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
        photosArray[i].defaultTextFormat = listformat;
        photosArray[i].selectable = false;
        photosArray[i].wordWrap = true;
        photosArray[i].text = photoname;
        photosArray[i].autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        photosArray[i].mouseEnabled = false;
        photoHighlights[i].addChildAt(photosArray[i], 1);


        //Load thumbFrames
        var thumbFrame:thmbFrame = new thmbFrame();
        thumbFrame.x= 962;
        thumbFrame.y= 21;
        photoHighlights[i].addChildAt(thumbFrame, 1);
        thmbFrames.push(thmbFrame);

        MediaPage.photoSelect.photoList.addChild(photoHighlights[i]);
        yTmp = yTmp + 153;
    }
}

function  highlightOvr(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.rectngles.alpha=1;             
    event.target.photosArray.textColor = 0x000000;
    event.target.thmbFrames.color = 0x000000;
    event.target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, highlightOut);  
}

function  highlightOut(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.rectngles.alpha = 0;
    event.target.photosArray.textColor = 0x0DAC54;
    event.target.thmbFrames.color = 0x0DAC54;
    event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, highlightOut);
}
```

The issue now has become one of referring back to the children of the placed movieClips. I know this isn't right:

```
event.target.rectngles.alpha = 0;
```

I just don't know what is. How do I refer to the generated movieClips and their children?

I know there is a simple way to do this, but I don't know what it is.

Also, it seems the way I'm doing this is a bit convoluted according to ShaunHusain's response. Any links to clearly worded resources explaining more efficient ways of accomplishing this are much appreciated.

Thanks Once Again,
-T.

EDIT: Fixed some incredibly stupid stuff I did.

Comment: Just FYI this isn't the "regular" way to go, in both Flash and Flex UI components there's an ability to define a renderer for a list, that's where you'd normally do your drawing for each element.  The list control does a thing called item renderer recycling where it will create an object pool of renderers to use and re-use those renderers as the user scrolls (applying new data to them and adjusting their positions).  What you're doing isn't strictly speaking wrong, but doing this all manually you'll lose the performance benefit of renderer recycling. (not a big deal for a small list)

Comment: Hey Shaun,
thank you for the tip! Unfortunately though, everything you're talking about kind of went over my head. I'd really like to understand it though. Is there somewhere that I can read up on that? And if possible, somewhere that breaks it down pretty simply? I'm pretty green at this point.

Comment: do you have functions defined inside of your for loop or is that a typo?

Comment: Yes those functions are defined inside of my loop. I've heard this is wrong, however, I don't know how to refer to object... Okay, nevermind. That was kind of obvious. So now the functions are outside of the loop. Still having an issue with "A term is undefined and has no properties." I updated the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very simple answer I was looking for was the use of the getChildAt command. So instead of:

```
function  highlightOvr(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.rectngles.alpha=1;             
    event.target.photosArray.textColor = 0x000000;
    event.target.thmbFrames.color = 0x000000;
    event.target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, highlightOut);  
}
```

It should be:

```
function  highlightOvr(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.getChildAt(0).alpha=1;             
    event.target.getChildAt(1).textColor = 0x000000;
    event.target.getChildAt(2).color = 0x000000;
    event.target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, highlightOut);  
}
```

I might add that the .color command was being used incorrectly. I was trying to apply it to a movie clip, when instead I needed to create a new ColorTransform variable with my desired color, and apply it like so:

```
var MyColorTransform:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
MyColorTransform.color = 0x000000;

event.target.getChildAt(2).transform.colorTransform = MyColorTransform;
```